# MongoDB findOne() returns null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

In my server.js I have a route for deleting a specific quote from the database.

```
//DELETE
app.delete('/quotes/:QUID', async(req, res) => {
    console.log(`DELETE ROUTE GOT HIT WITH ${req.params.QUID}`)
    let query = {
        "UID": req.params.QUID
    }
    const cursor = await collection.findOne(query, (err, result) => {
        console.log(`Error is ${err}`)
        console.log(` Result is ${result}`)
    })
    await collection.deleteOne({"UID": req.params.QUID})
    res.send(cursor);
})
```

When the route gets hit I send the ID of quote to delete in the route. Below is the structure of the data in the database.

```
_id: ObjectId("5f531a3ce52e9f3bc6c3b21c"), 
UID: 996779
name: "Neel Patel"
quote: "Yolo"
```

But when the route gets hit, it returns null even though the document with that specific UID exists in the database. Below is the console.log() output.

```
Listening on port 3000
Connection successful!
DELETE ROUTE GOT HIT WITH 996779
Error is null
Result is null
```

I am not sure what the problem is. First I thought it had to with the function not being async, so I added async in front of the (req, res) function, but the problem was still present.

Comment: If you do the same query manually (from mongo cli) does it work?

Comment: @Wyck I don't know how to run the query from mongo cli

Comment: To delete using mongo cli:  ***WARNING*** this will actually delete the document from your db, so hopefully you have 
 a way to recreate it.  `db.collectionname.deleteOne({UID: 996779})`  You must substitute `collectionname` with the actual name of your collection.

Comment: It still doesn't return anything.

Comment: `await collection.deleteOne(query)` should be sufficient.  Remove the unnecessary and incorrect `findOne` statement completely (it doesn't take a callback).  Try with just `const result = await collection.deleteOne(query)`  And then you can check it with `console.log(\`deleted ${result.deletedCount} document(s).\`);`

Comment: So I figured the problem. It was because the "QUID" in the route was being read as a string so I had to use parseInt() function to convert it to an Integer so it would know to look for an integer in the database.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in my query. The QUID from the route was being read as a string but I needed it as an Integer. So I modified my query like the following:

```
let query = {
        "UID": parseInt(req.params.QUID)
    }
```

Comment: Glad you solved it, I was in the middle of typing this out, heh